# Trying to super-impose an image via background-image:url(...) over an image that's also background-image:url(...) - not working

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to put an image OVER an existing image, by way of CSS `background-image:url(...)`.

I have the following class:

```
.imageContainer {
    width:318px;
    height:207px;
    background-image:url('images/Generic Chrome Notification no_image.png');
}
```

Then, I have this class:

```
.iconImage
    {
        width:45px;
        height:45px;
        background-image:url("https://image.s7.sfmc-content.com/lib/fe9613727166077c73/m/1/bf347e87-2e3f-4e6d-9c5f-806d3ef1e4af.png");
}
```

Finally, here's the output:
[image]

The white square in the image above (number 1) is actually part of the number 2 image.  I have my HTML laid out such that the white square above corresponds to the first CSS class mentioned above.  But, I don't see the image there.  I F12'd Dev Tools to make sure that the `<div class="iconImage"></div>` was actually in the white square, and it is.

[image]

So, is it possible to super-impose images on top of each other by using `background-image:url(...)`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. I can tell you that you can specify multiple images in a `background` declaration with a comma (top of the list = top layer). Though this seems a bit hacky instead of just placing your image in the content.

Comment: Please include the markup you used in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (background) image you are using in `.iconImage` is 180x180 px large in original. Since you don't define a size, it is displayed in original size, but only a part of it is visible. Here's what the image looks like:

[image]

Its size is 180x180px, major parts of it (top and bottom above and below  "AMGEN®") are just white, and only its top left is visible in your screenshot: It's a 45x45px white *part* (the upper left corner) of the image. So everything works as desired, but it looks like there is no image, since that top left part is just white...

The one thing you have to change to show the whole image scaled down (which you probably want) is to add `background-size: cover`...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, here is an example with 2 images overlaid on top of a another image

```css
.img1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587613754760-cd9a285831b3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.img2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589292943875-996861aa36a3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=200&q=60) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.img3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589469884538-4e5d63671b09?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=200&q=60) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="img1">
  <div class="img2"></div>
  <div class="img3"></div>
</div>
```